# Collect Values not working as expected in ArcGIS ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder

I am trying to iterate through a folder of rasters, reclassify each raster, then combine all of the reclassified rasters using Cell Statistics (to get the overall SUM of the reclassified rasters).  I have read countless help forums and my Model should be working, but I am not able to connect the "Cell Statistics" block to the "Output Values" from the "Collect Values."  For some reason, the only variables available to be under the "Cell Statistics" input picker box are "Raster" and "Reclassified Rasters" - I would expect "Output Values" to be listed as well, as that is the link I am trying to make.

[image: ModelBuilder]

[image: CellStatsPicker]

Answer (score 2):

You need to split this into two models. Have everything up to collect values in one model, then make output value of the collects tool a parameter.

Drag this all into a new model that has the cell statistics tool. You only want the cell statistic tool to run once so it should not be in the same model as the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, even if it does not show up in your drop down menu, you could connect to the results of your collect tool. Therefore, you can draw a line from your "output values" green ellips to your "cell statistics" tools using the "connector button" (third button from the right)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this, but found if I ran the model first (when it was in the same state as yours above, with Cell Statistics still in white), it iterated the rasters and populated the Output Values. After that I was able to connect the Output Values straight to Cell Statistics (using the connector tool) as the Input Rasters. Then my model worked.

I posted [my model in answer to another question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76655/how-to-iterate-through-bands-of-raster-using-arcgis-10-1-modelbuilder/95275#95275)