# Iterating and extracting subdatasets from hdf files and exporting data into MS excel using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, modis, arcgis-10.5, hdf

I have a large amount (10 years of data!) of MODIS LST .hdf files that I need to load into arc, extract subdatasets and import data into excel so it can be analysed. As I have such a large dataset I would like to automate this process as much as possibly.

I have limited experience of using ModelBuilder and python, but I'm willing to learn both. I have played around with ModelBuilder and from help from other Q&As (e.g. [Using ModelBuilder to Iterate and extract subdatasets with in hdf file and project subdatasets?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141605/using-modelbuilder-to-iterate-and-extract-subdatasets-with-in-hdf-file-and-proje)) and have built this:

[image]

---

Have been able to extract subdatasets and the pixels match up with the original image. I used this:

[image]

However, it seems that it runs the process for each .hdf file in the folder, but then it overwrites the output for each file so the final output is just one image (the last image processed).

Is there a way for the output to be a folder so that each image gets put into that folder?

---

I am now coming up with this error:

[image]

So it's saying the file extension does not support subdatasets, does anyone know how to solve this? I have tried all the file formats and none of them work!

Comment: You need to be using inline substitution when generating the output name in the extract subdataset tool. Don't know what that is? It's all in the [help file](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/examples-of-inline-model-variable-substitution.htm).

Comment: If you need to ask about ArcPy instead then you will need to include a code snippet as your starting point.

Comment: Here you are asking followup questions, which substantially change the original question, when your first question has already been answered.  I think you should accept that answer and start a new question.  https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649  Also, please always include errors as text rather than pictures so that they are available to future searches.

Answer (score 1):

You need to dynamically name the output.

You have a nice variable in your model - Name.

To use this in the output, set the output dataset as %Name%_additionaltext

Replace additionaltext with whatever text you want, or remove it.

Each output will now get a unique name and wont be overwritten.

%Name% will insert the Name of the current raster, so if the first raster is named 'test1', the output will be test1_additionaltext.

Insert name into the output raster parameter in Extract Subdataset:

[image]

Here is some documentation on [inline model variable substitution](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/examples-of-inline-model-variable-substitution.htm) - same page linked by Hornbydd in the comments.